# Getting 404 error after login intermittently

Tags: error-handling

We are using `Sitecore 9.3` in our 2 portals. We are getting an error intermittently.
We are using `Azure AD B2C` for login.
After logging in to the site, when the Microsoft page redirects back to the portal login page - https://portalname.com/login and after that, it shows `IIS 404` error page.

We tried to debug the code. But it is not hitting any breakpoints.

And this error is intermittent. Sometimes, it redirects correctly. Other times it does not.
This is a priority issue. Can anybody suggest any fixes or suggestions to troubleshoot?

Comment: Is it intermittent on the same user or different users? if only on some users, it could be the number of AD groups they have assigned? Any errors in identity server logs?